# How to export every table to csv in a kdb+ database?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

Assume my kdb+ database has a few tables. How can I export all tables to csv files where the name of each csv is same as the table name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There may be a number of ways to approach this, one solution could be:

```
 q)t1:([]a:1 2 3;b:1 2 3)
 q)t2:([]a:1 2 3;b:1 2 3;c:1 2 3)
 q){save `$(string x),".csv"} each tables[]
   `:t1.csv`:t2.csv
```

ref: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/filewords/#save

If you wish to specify the directory of the file being saved down then you could enhance the function like so:

```
q){[dir;tSym] save ` sv dir,(`$ raze string tSym,`.csv)}[`:C:/Users/dhughes1/Documents;] each tables[]
  `:C:/Users/dhughes1/Documents/t1.csv`:C:/Users/dhughes1/Documents/t2.csv
```

Comment: Note that it would get a lot more complex than this if you're talking about a historical database with date-partitioned/splayed tables etc.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method to `save` is to use [`0:`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/filenumbers/#0-text-files) to [prepare](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/filenumbers/#prepare-text) text, specifying a delimiter of ",":

```
q)tab:([]a:1 2 3;b:`a`b`c)
q)show t:","0:tab
"a,b"
"1,a"
"2,b"
"3,c"
```

And again to [save](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/filenumbers/#save-text) text:

```
q)`:tab 0: t
`:tab
```

The advantage of this method is that the delimiter can be specified before saving to disk.